# C# store app can't load json data

Tags: c#, json, windows-store-apps

I'm a beginner to C# Store apps and i have a JSON file that I want to see into the tile's of my screen. the problem is my method will not retreive any data at all. 
Second question, in order to show data onto my screen, does it have to be an observerable collection?

```
public class DataConnection
{
    public DataConnection()
    {

    }

    public async Task getDataFromJson()
    {
        Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/ProductData.json");

        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
        string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();

        foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonArray)
        {
            List<ProductGroup> groupList = new List<ProductGroup>();
            JsonObject groupObject = groupValue.GetObject();
            ProductGroup group = new ProductGroup(groupObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Subtitle"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                        groupObject["Description"].GetString());

            foreach (JsonValue itemValue in groupObject["Items"].GetArray())
            {
                JsonObject itemObject = itemValue.GetObject();
                group.Items.Add(new ProductItem(itemObject["UniqueId"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Title"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Artikelnummer"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["VerkoopprijsInBtw"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["VerkoopprijsExBtw"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Inkoopprijs"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["ActualStock"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Marge"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Eenheid"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["ImagePath"].GetString(),
                                                   itemObject["Description"].GetString()));

            }
            groupList.Add(group);
        }
    }
}
```

the problem seems to be in the line:
            Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/ProductData.json");

```
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
```

where the debugger just ends the method and proceeds without any data being retreived. The data in the json file is tested and correct, so thats not the issue.
I copied this method from a standard Gridapp so the code should be fine, i know the problem (probably) occurs in the StorageFile. Did i miss anything?

Any tips would be nice!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, I'd check your path and make sure that the full path is correct (which you probably have done, but still good to note). Secondly, I'd see if `file` is being filled with the proper file. Add a breakpoint right after it and see if it's being loaded. You could also call `GetBasicPropertiesAsync` and check its `Size`. Thirdly, your collection doesn't *need* to be an `ObservableCollection` unless you are filling it or modifying it after it's been loaded into the UI. If it's a static list, it does not (but make sure to set the source **after** you've loaded the data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers but the problem was something stupid. For the people having the same problem:

I managed to fix it to put the json file also in the debugger in your project under \bin\Debug\AppX (it diddn't go there automatically and you won't see anything at all or will not retrieve data if you want to get the data like i did with a storagefile).

thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by your async call.

Try to call *GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync* **synchronously** as follows:

`StorageFile file = StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri).Result;`

Notice that I omitted the `await` keyword and fetched the `Result` property.

Comment: I got the same problem and try your method. It works!

Comment: However, the process   is not always successful since the system throws a `System.UriFormatException`. If I use `StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);`, it throws `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException`.